# Как объявить массив указателей своего класса в c#

Tags: c#

Нужно что-то подобное:

```
HPDateOfBirth*[] births = new HPDateOfBirth[5];
```

Comment: В этой строке ошибка: "Не удается получить адрес, определить размер или объявить указатель на управляемый тип ("HPDateOfBirth")"

Comment: Если вы хотите дополнить вопрос, не пишите комментарий, а редактируйте вопрос. Кстати, а зачем вам сырые указатели в C#? Вы скорее всего делаете что-то не то.

Comment: Предположу, что вам нужно просто `HPDateOfBirth[] births = new HPDateOfBirth[5];`.

Comment: @VladD задание для лабораторной

Comment: @VladD "В основной программе (функции main) объявить массив указателей на) объявить массив указателей на
базовый (родительского) класс"

Comment: Даже для лабораторной я бы не рекомандовал использовать сырые указатели.

Comment: Вы уверены, что задание правильное? Скорее всего имеются в виду ссылки (reference), а не указатели (pointer).

Comment: @VladD понял, спасибо

Comment: @VladD Ну написано массив указателей, возможно задание задано некорректно

Comment: Предположу, что в данный момент в учебном заведении вы проходите другой язык (c, c++), но лично вы решили писать код на c# (такое неоднократно встречалось), вот и страдаете теперь от несоответствия семантики языков.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov именно на c#

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Скорее всего методичка для c++

Comment: stackalloc же нужен для массива через указатели